# import CSV as double?

Tags: matlab, data-import

I was hoping for some help with data import. For background, I have tested 30 products, 3 times each giving a total of 90 unique files (grouped into three's).

Each of my raw data files has a different number of rows and includes a header row with 9 columns (I'm not interested in the headers). In this instance I'm only interested in obtaining columns 1,3 & 4.

I've moved all my .csv's into one folder and I've used a file grabber (obtained from Stackoverflow) to bring the csv data into the workspace, like so:

```
[file,dir,filterIndex] =  uigetfile( ...
{'*.csv', '*.csv';
'*.*',  'All Files (*.*)'}, ...
'Select files',...
'Multiselect', 'on');

if ischar(file)
    file = {file};
end
n = length(file);
d = cell(n,1);
```

This brings in a <90x1> cell.
The following is what I'm using to import the data and convert from cells to doubles - as you can see it's fairly labour intensive...Does anyone have a method to reduce the amount of copy-pasting I'm doing?

```
for k = 1:n
fid = fopen([dir,file{k}]);
d{k} = textscan(fid,'%f %f %f %f %*[^\n]',...
       'delimiter',',','HeaderLines',1);
fclose(fid);
end

A = vertcat(d{:});
Q = cell2mat(A(:,[1,3,4]));
s1 = cell2mat(A(1,[1,3,4]));
s2 = cell2mat(A(2,[1,3,4]));
s3 = cell2mat(A(3,[1,3,4]));
ss1 = (s1(1,2)+s2(1,2)+s3(1,2))/3;
s4 = cell2mat(A(4,[1,3,4]));
s5 = cell2mat(A(5,[1,3,4]));
s6 = cell2mat(A(6,[1,3,4]));
ss2 = (s4(1,2)+s5(1,2)+s6(1,2))/3;
.
.
.
s88 = cell2mat(A(88,[1,3,4]));
s89 = cell2mat(A(89,[1,3,4]));
s90 = cell2mat(A(90,[1,3,4]));
ss30 = (s88(1,2)+s89(1,2)+s90(1,2))/3;
```

if possible I would be happy to have the data in consecutive columns in one single matrix (although, as I previously mentioned, the files are different lengths).
The matrix 'Q' was just a test - it brings all the data in but in three really long columns which is not what I want.

I'm adding some data from the csv's as requested:

```
's1 = Time,Voltage_0,Med_PSense,FC_Flow_Meter,Voltage_3,Voltage_4,Voltage_5,Voltage_6,Voltage_7
0.0000,0.2431,-0.1334,-0.2381,1.4003,1.3917,1.3986,1.4045,1.4047
0.0100,0.2119,-0.1120,-0.1878,1.4029,1.3968,1.3910,1.3994,1.3996
0.0200,0.2119,-0.1120,-0.2130,1.4080,1.3917,1.3961,1.3994,1.4022
0.0300,0.2119,-0.1120,-0.2297,1.4003,1.3993,1.3961,1.3994,1.4047
0.0400,0.2015,-0.0905,-0.2297,1.3978,1.3968,1.3935,1.3994,1.3996`

's2 = Time,Voltage_0,Med_PSense,FC_Flow_Meter,Voltage_3,Voltage_4,Voltage_5,Voltage_6,Voltage_7
0.0000,0.2639,-0.1334,-0.2381,1.4003,1.3993,1.4037,1.3994,1.3920
0.0100,0.2431,-0.0905,-0.2381,1.4003,1.4019,1.4037,1.3994,1.3945
0.0200,0.2535,-0.1762,-0.2465,1.4029,1.4044,1.3986,1.3994,1.3996
0.0300,0.2119,-0.1548,-0.2130,1.4029,1.3993,1.3935,1.3994,1.3996
0.0400,0.2223,-0.1334,-0.2046,1.4003,1.3917,1.3910,1.3994,1.4022'

's3 = Time,Voltage_0,Med_PSense,FC_Flow_Meter,Voltage_3,Voltage_4,Voltage_5,Voltage_6,Voltage_7
0.0000,0.2223,-0.1762,-0.2465,1.4003,1.3993,1.4011,1.3918,1.3920
0.0100,0.2015,-0.1548,-0.2130,1.4054,1.3968,1.3910,1.3994,1.3996
0.0200,0.2535,-0.0691,-0.2465,1.3927,1.3993,1.4062,1.4020,1.4022
0.0300,0.2535,-0.1334,-0.2465,1.4003,1.3993,1.3986,1.3994,1.3920
0.0400,0.2119,-0.1120,-0.2381,1.4003,1.3993,1.4011,1.3994,1.4022'
```

The lengths of the csv's given are:

```
s1 = 9330 elements long
s2 = 9210 elements long
s3 = 6180 elements long
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: If you can have the data in 1 matrix, do you mind padding the uneven lengths with zeros or NaNs or something ?

Comment: Not at all - Ultimately I'm wanting to take the averages across the three files and plot time (col.1) vs. pressure(col4) and flow(col3). I can plot pressure and flow on the same axis for my purposes

Comment: Could you give your .csv's?

Comment: I've added samples of some raw data - it doesn't look pretty! You're welcome to the original files, however, I'm not sure how to upload here. Thanks for your help

Comment: First, the loop in loading the file cannot be simplified, the only part is the individual `cell2mat` which you call on each cell, which can be simplified using a `cellfun` something like `cell2mat(cellfun(@(x) cell2mat(x),C,'un',0))`

Answer (score 0):

Input files:
s1.csv, s2.csv, s3.csv

```
names = {'s1','s2','s3'};
delimiterIn = ',';
headerlinesIn = 1;

% make a structure with all data
for i = 1:length(names)
    all.data(i) = importdata([char(names(i)),'.csv'],delimiterIn ,headerlinesIn)
end

% take columns 1,3,4 (from s1)
all.data(1).data(:,[1,3,4])
% take columns 1,3,4 (from s2)
all.data(2).data(:,[1,3,4])
% ...
```

This selection can be realized in a loop...
And, and what needs to be done with that further?